# Parsing XML into HashMap using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, hashmap

I thoroughly search answer to my question but didn't get it. My task is something like that. I have an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<users>
    <user id="1">
        <login>james.bond</login>
        <password>12345</password>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </user>
    <user id="2">
        <login>john.doe</login>
        <password>67890</password>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </user>
</users>
```

I want to parse it to HashMap where keys and values should be something like that (node names through a period as a keys and values of these nodes as a values in map):

**K:** users.user.1.login **V:** james.bond

**K:** users.user.1.password **V:** 12345

etc...

On the very moment I have:

```
public Map<String, String> parse(File file) {
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);

            doc = db.parse(file);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            System.out.println("Parser was not configured properly [LOG IT!]");
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read input file [LOG IT!]");
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            System.out.println("Problem parsing the file [LOG I!]");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ae) {
            System.out.println("Please specify an XML source [LOG IT!]");
        }

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        return stepThrough(root);
    }

private Map<String, String> stepThrough(Node node) {
        String nodeName =  node.getNodeName();

        if (!nodeName.equals("#text")) {
            buildedKey.append(nodeName).append(".");
        }

        if (node.getNodeValue() != null && !node.getNodeValue().matches("^\\W*$")) {
            parsedMap.put(buildedKey.toString(),node.getNodeValue());
        }

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (node.hasAttributes()) {
                NamedNodeMap startAttr = node.getAttributes();
                for (int i = 0; i < startAttr.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node attr = startAttr.item(i);
                    buildedKey.append(attr.getNodeValue()).append(".");
                }
            }
        }

        for (Node child = node.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
            stepThrough(child);
        }

        return parsedMap;
    }
```

And I have last key in my map for example:
**users.user.1.login.password.enabled.user.2.login.password.enabled**

In other words all node names are concatenating.

Would you help me? Thanks!

P.S.: I have one restriction and I can not use libs like XStream...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using same global `buildedKey` for all traversing and you don't remove added part when you're coming back to from `stepThrough`. Simple solution would be to pass `buildedKey` as parameter instead of using global variable:

```
private Map<String, String> stepThrough(Node node, String buildedKey) {
        String nodeName =  node.getNodeName();

        if (!nodeName.equals("#text")) {
            buildedKey += nodeName + ".";
        }

        if (node.getNodeValue() != null && !node.getNodeValue().matches("^\\W*$")) {
            parsedMap.put(buildedKey,node.getNodeValue());
        }

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (node.hasAttributes()) {
                NamedNodeMap startAttr = node.getAttributes();
                for (int i = 0; i < startAttr.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node attr = startAttr.item(i);
                    buildedKey += attr.getNodeValue() + ".";
                }
            }
        }

        for (Node child = node.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
            stepThrough(child, buildedKey);
        }

        return parsedMap;
    }
```

Also you better use `String` for `buildedKey` instead of `StringBuilder` because `String` is immutable and you don't want to spoil buildedKey in one node and use same spoiled key in another.

Comment: Thank you, colleague! I knew that answere is somewhere near :)